# processsing each element of dictionary of lists using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

suppose i have a dictionary such as

```
dict = {A:[1,2,3], B:[4,5,6], C:[7,8,9], ......}
```

I want to process each element of a particular key's list one after other but the individual keys could be processed in parallel using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
  ex.submit(process_element, contents of A)
  ex.submit(process_element, contents of B)
  ex.submit(process_element, contents of C)
  .
  .
  .
```

So the output should be

```
result of process_element A[0]
result of process_element B[0]
result of process_element C[0]

.
.
.

result of process_element A[1]
```

but not necessary in that order

what is wrong with the above method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're passing the list, but instead a variable named 'A'.  I'm not sure when you run your code why your not getting an error.  What you want is below

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
  ex.submit(process_element, dict['A'])
  ex.submit(process_element, dict['B'])
  ex.submit(process_element, dict['C'])
```

To process each element one by one, then you could simply use a list construction:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
  procsA = [ex.submit(process_element, elem) for elem in dict['A']
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: if i use this all the elements of dict['A'] are passed into the funtion process_element at once.. i want to pass them one at a time

Comment: Do you need them to specifically be in order 0, 1, 2 etc?

Comment: So the elements of A,B,C can be processed concurrently but no two elements in A or B or C can be processed at the same time.

The order is not important

Comment: Process_elements is a function that has a variable delay depending on the response of the API depending on the elements in A, B, C